# Read data from mongodb in chunks

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-batch, batch-processing

I receive data continuously from users in form of rest (**Spring Java server**) request and store them in `Mongodb`.

I have a use case in which my client say to upload this data once in a week in form of text file but that their system has a **upload limit of 200 MB**.

Consider that if I received 1GB data in a week.

**Currently how I am trying to solve my use-case is**

- Read all data from MongoDB where date is in between `START_DATE_OF_WEEK and END_DATE_OF_WEEK`
- Create text files of less than 200MB e.g `week11_1.txt`,
  `week11_2.txt` and so on...

**The current challenge I am facing** If I solve using above approach is how to read from MongoDB, stop when data size is about 190MB, then create a text file and upload it and repeat this till no data of a particular week is left unread.

I will be very thankful to you if you help me in solving this use-case using the approach above or with any better approach.

Comment: I think this is entirely too broad a question, but I also think you are approaching it from the wrong way. So instead of asking MongoDB to return 200MB when translated to text, why not just split the text files themselves at that point. It should be relatively simple to count the bytes written, and all you are really doing ( though a broad topic ) is switching which "stream" to output do. So this should not have anything to do with the datasource. Manage the output instead.

Comment: are you suggesting to read whole week data at once from MongoDB and then write that data to various text files.

Comment: Bingo! Off the top of my head I can think of doing the exact same thing with several different database engines at least 5 times before. Counting bytes on an output stream is easy. Don't overthink it.

Comment: ok, thanks for ur answer